# FSUTIL in GB space left

Tags: batch-file, command, fsutil

I got a batch file that does the following.

```
echo Server 1 C:\>>output.txt
fsutil volume diskfree \\IPISHERE\d$>>output.txt
echo ---------------------------------------------------------- >>output.txt
```

This then displays data as

```
Total # of free bytes        : 71942455296
Total # of bytes             : 131623546880
Total # of avail free bytes  : 71942455296
```

Please can some one help so I can convert it in to GBs?

Comment: The `SET /A` command can only do arithmetic operations on 32 bit integers.  The maximum +- value is 2,147,483,647.

Comment: If you don't need precision you could just drop the 6 LS digits, or drop the 6 LS digits and round up. Then insert the decimal point in the appropriate place as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('fsutil volume diskfree C:') do for %%c in (%%b) do (
   set "D=%%c"
   set /A "D1=!D:~0,-8!,D2=1!D:~-8,-4!-10000,D3=1!D:~-4!-10000"
   for /L %%f in (1,1,3) do ( rem Number of divisions: KB, MB, GB
      set /A "F=0,C=0"
      for /L %%i in (1,1,3) do ( rem Quads in the number of bytes: 3*4 = 12 digits
         set /A "F+=^!^!D%%i"
         if !F! neq 0 set /A "D=C*10000+D%%i,D%%i=D/1024,C=D%%1024"
      )
   )
   set /A "C=C*10000/1024+10000
   echo %%a: !D3!.!C:~1,2! GB
)
```

Output example:

```
C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\Test> fsutil volume diskfree C:
Número total de bytes libres            : 406596222976
Número total de bytes                   : 474821423104
Número total de bytes libres disponibles: 406596222976

C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\Test> test.bat
Número total de bytes libres            : 378.67 GB
Número total de bytes                   : 442.21 GB
Número total de bytes libres disponibles: 378.67 GB
```