# Batch: Handle numbers above 2^32

Tags: string, windows, batch-file, int, long-integer

I want to make an action in a batch file dependent on my free storage space, but it fails (interestingly only sometimes), because the free space is more than 2GB, making the variable not settable.

This is the batch file:

```
cd "C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\Screen Recordings\Auto"
for /F "usebackq delims== tokens=2" %%x in (`wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='C:'" get FreeSpace /format:value`) do (set FreeSpace=%%x)
if (%FreeSpace%) LSS (2499522027520) (
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /t:w /o:d "C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\Screen Recordings\Auto\*.flv"') do (
del "%%a"
goto :breakLoop
))
:breakLoop
exit
```

A lot of this is just workarounds for Windows' weirdnesses, the important part is: `set FreeSpace=%%x`
That `x` is a string straight out of the live disk data, which should be converted to a number, but since it's bigger than 2<sup>32</sup>, that fails (and it makes it a string, making the comparison in the next line a string comparison, which is not at all what I want).
I can also not divide it by a number, because that would require it being a number first.

**Would I have to use the gross hack of chopping off digits at the end by changing the length of the string (if yes, how?) or is there a way to have proper `long` numbers in a batch file?**

I found [this script](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/battech_math_chop_example.txt) ([archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20160405014558/http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/battech_math_chop_example.txt)) that actually works, but I don't know how. Which part of it chops off the digits and which is the important part that I need? I can't let it sum up all folder sizes every time, because the script runs every 20 seconds.

Comment: Windows command prompt does not support numbers exceeding the range of signed 32-bit integers. However, you could perhaps truncate the last say 6 digits so you have a rounded-down MBytes value which will most probably not exceed 2^31 - 1...

Comment: O.k. , but how?

Comment: Use [sub-string expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html); for example: `set "FreeSpace=%FreeSpace:~,-6%" & if not defined FreeSpace set "FreeSpace=0"` (before your `if` query); and remove the parentheses from the comparison expressions (use the correct [`if` syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html))!

Comment: Your error is coming from the IF comparison regarding 32 bit integers.  It is not coming from the SET command.

Comment: @aschipfl That seems to cut off 5 digits, weird. Anyway, it works, can you please post it as an answer?

Comment: Also I have to remove the brackets around the numbers.

Comment: Yes Fabian, @aschipfl, told you to remove the parentheses.  They are not brackets.  When comparing numbers with the IF command you should only give it the numbers to compare.  When the IF command sees other characters besides numbers it then makes a string comparison.

Comment: Yes, `set "FreeSpace=%FreeSpace:~,-6%"`  cuts off 5 digits + `<CR>` character i.e. **6 characters alltogether**. See Dave Benham's [*`WMIC` and `FOR /F`: A fix for the trailing `<CR>` problem*](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266).

Comment: You may get an _exact_ conversion from Bytes to MB or GB in a relatively simple way. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46913373/fsutil-in-gb-space-left/46923884#46923884)

Comment: Thanks! But for my case, that's not that important. The difference between 1000x1000 and 1024x1024 is less than the inaccuracies that I get from the disk info anyway. And the script is just there to ensure that I always have some space left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible in Windows command prompt to handle numbers outside of the range of signed 32-bit integers which range from -2<sup>31</sup> = -2147483648 to 2<sup>31</sup> - 1 = 2147483647.

You could however remove a couple of digits using [sub-string expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html), say 6, on the right to have a rounded-down number of Mega-Bytes instead of Bytes and use the result for a numeric comparison, like this:

```cmd
cd "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Screen Recordings\Auto"
set "FreeSpace=0"
for /F "usebackq skip=1" %%x in (`wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='C:'" get FreeSpace^,Size`) do (set "FreeSpace=%%x")

rem // Remove the last 6 digits to get MBytes:
set "FreeSpaceMB=%FreeSpace:~,-6%"
rem // Ensure to not leave an empty value behind:
if not defined FreeSpaceMB set "FreeSpaceMB=0"

if %FreeSpaceMB% LSS 2499522 (
    for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /A:-D /T:W /O:D "C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\Screen Recordings\Auto\*.flv"') do (
        del "%%a"
        goto :breakLoop
    )
)
:breakLoop
exit /B
```

Of course you lose precision but this could probably be acceptable for the purpose at hand.

I also changed the `for /F` loop that captures the `wmic` output in order to avoid Unicode conversion artefacts like orphaned carriage-return (CR) characters, which would result in the variable `FreeSpace` to contain a number plus a CR. That is why I queried also the value `Size` although it is not needed, but so the `FreeSpace` value is not the last one which might be tailed by a CR.

By the way, note that I removed the superfluous parentheses from the [`if`](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) command line.